# Teamcity default system properties not set

Tags: teamcity

In my gradle script I try to use the default system properties. The documentation tells me that teamcity.buildType.id and teamcity.build.id is only set in the system properties an not as environment variables, so my only way is to access them via `System.getProperty("%system.teamcity.buildType.id%")`. But it tells me it is not defined.

I tried to reference to `%system.teamcity.buildType.id%` via my own environment variable but it tells me this `Parameter "env.teamcity.buildType.id=%system.teamcity.buildType.id%" is not fully resolved, using as is.`

I also printed out every system and environment variable. It printed a whole list but not any of the default system properties which should be set by teamcity.

How can I access them and why aren't they not set automatically?